# What is the relation between coefficients selected by an Oracle-procedure and significant coefficients?

Tags: statistical-significance, feature-selection, least-squares, lasso, oracle

As proved by Zou (2006), the adaptive LASSO enjoys the Oracle Property in the sense that it does variable selection as if it knew the true (sparse) model. However, in the early days, the standard hypothesis testing in e.g. OLS should also point in the direction of which variables to leave out in the model due to insignificance.

How does the Oracle Property and the significance test relate to each other?